# Outlook Add-in not loading in 64bit OS and MS Office 2007

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in

I have created a Installer for my Outlook add-in. It works fine on windows 8 and windows 7 with both 64 bit OS and 32 bit OS and office 2010 and 2013.
**My problem is with windows 7(64-bit) and MS Office 2007.**

Registry entry is created fine in the location :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\myAddin
```

Also load behavior is 3
Load behavior is 3 when outlook is opened first time.
But I noticed one more thing that if i go into inactive add-ins and try to activate my add-in then the load behavior changes to zero.

I have also checked "VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS" for any  vsto error messages or exception but no exceptions are there.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found only one solution to my situation without installing office 2007 SP2 and SP3..
That is HLKM to HKCU registry replication given on following link:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819389/c-sharp-vsto-outlook-2007-strange-difference-between-hklm-and-hkcu?rq=1

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2007/09/04/deploying-your-vsto-add-in-to-all-users-part-i.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2007/09/05/deploying-your-vsto-add-in-to-all-users-part-ii.aspx
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Outlook 2007 will not load AddIns from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
Fortunately Microsoft has a fix for this here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976811

Comment: Thanks for reply Oliver. I found the hotfix download link but i am not able to test the same because the hotfix exe is only for 32 bit machines

Comment: That should be fine. Afaik there is just a 32Bit Version of Outlook 2007, you can't get it as 64Bit.

Comment: You can download this hotfix or you can install Office 2007 SP2 or SP3. both include the hotfix.

Comment: thnaks for ur help..i meant to say that Hotfix exe does not run on 64 bit machine. i didnt find any compatible hotfix...Is installing sp2 or sp3 is the only option now?

Comment: I always thought that the fix runs on 64Bit. If not, I guess the service packs will be you only option.